# Change order of cols with push and pull Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid, col

I just discovered the "push" and "pull" classes in Bootstrap, but am having a lot of trouble implementing them the way I'd like. On XS screens, my content appears as follows, which is correct:

```
|A||B||C|
```

But on SM screens, I need it to be:

```
|B|
|C|
|A|
```

My HTML is below. I tried adding "col-sm-push-10" to the div that contains my button, but that just pushed it to the right within it's own div. I need to actually MOVE this div down. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
       <ul class="prod-group">
         <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-10">
            <li><button type="button" class="btn">A</button></li>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-10">
            <li>B</li>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-10">
              <li>Cr</li>
           </div>
        </ul>    
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd want elements to stack vertically on xs screens, and remain horizontally on larger (sm) screens, so this is an unusual case where you actually want the opposite. Create the stacking `sm` layout first, then adjust for `xs` using push-pull.. A-B-C on large. B-C-A on mobile.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul class="row prod-group">
            <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-push-0">
                B
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-2 col-sm-10 col-xs-pull-0 col-sm-pull-0">
                C
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-10 col-xs-pull-8 col-sm-pull-0">
                A
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo** http://www.codeply.com/go/yMxh8sGwMZ

Also, don't forget to keep your columns inside a `row` for proper padding.

Comment: Yes, it's a weird case! Let me give this a try, thanks.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You should write your elements in order that you want to see on -sm-.
Then adjust their position at -xs-:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4">
        B
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4 col-xs-push-4">
        C
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-4 col-xs-pull-8">
        A
    </div>     
</div>
```

By the way, you should use ***li*** only as direct child of ***ul*** as well as not using other elements such as ***div*** directly inside ***ul***, because it is not valid.

Comment: This just retains the xs layout when my screen is at sm. How can I actually move the div containing B to the bottom of the row?

Comment: There is no way to move elements actually **up** and **down** with push/pull classes. But I corrected my answer according to your comment.